# Fogbugz like dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, user-interface, fogbugz

I am searching for a jquery plugin to get a fogbugz like dropdown menu so that you can type in the dropdown menu.

This is what it should look like: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/5910/Jing/2009-05-10_0937.swf ( the old video http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/5910/Jing/2009-05-10_0055.swf )

All the answers have been not giving me the typing part any other suggestions?

EDIT: I found something a bit like it: http://phone.witamean.net/sexy-combo/examples/index.html but there are a couple things that bug me: it doesn't select the whole string we clicking in the textbox and the dropbox doesn't show all options when clicking on the triangle

I found a working demo but its from ext :( http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/combos.html not jquery... but it has all the features I neet

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or URL of an example? Your question is really vague.

Comment: I updated my answer to show an option that includes the typing part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's usually called a combobox, you can find a nice jQuery one here:

http://jonathan.tang.name/code/jquery_combobox

Comment: but it doesn't have the writing part

Comment: changed the link to a better one (based on jQuery UI too)

Comment: Thanks a bunch I wanted to start writing my own tomorrow now I don't have to :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found one yet that has both auto-complete and the combo drop down arrow.  However, this [plug-in](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/) is close.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the jQuery chosen library: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ They seem to work really well and fallback gracefully to normal selects.

Answer (score 0):

I just released a jQuery plugin that does exactly this called [Improved Dropdown](http://improvingsoftware.com/2011/04/21/adding-combo-box-style-dropdowns-to-your-web-page/). It is posted in the plug-in library on the jQuery site. [Here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ImprovedDropdown) is a direct link to it.